# I'm trying to build standalone app for my react native project used expo cli to design. But the build stops at midway and shows the below error

Tags: build, expo, react-native

node_modules@expo\vector-icons\build\vendor\react-native-vector-icons\lib\create-icon-set.js: # could not be cloned.
Error: # could not be cloned.
at Object.serialize (node:v8:260:7)
at _default (D:\React\CanReel\node_modules@babel\core\lib\transformation\util\clone-deep.js:16:30)
at normalizeFile (D:\React\CanReel\node_modules@babel\core\lib\transformation\normalize-file.js:52:36)
at normalizeFile.next ()
at run (D:\React\CanReel\node_modules@babel\core\lib\transformation\index.js:31:50)
at run.next ()
at D:\React\CanReel\node_modules@babel\core\lib\transform-ast.js:20:41
at Generator.next ()
at evaluateSync (D:\React\CanReel\node_modules\gensync\index.js:251:28)

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed this error by deleting node modules folder then killed metro bundler then running by npx react-native run-android command